# Как заставить окно просмотра скрывать все, что выходит за его границы?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Фоновая картинка задана блоку шириной 1200px через псевдоэлемент, чтобы выходил за края родителя,
как сделать так, чтобы когда окно сжималось до ширины псевдоэлемента, границы окна обрезали содержимое, без горизонтального скроллбара и отступов, показанных ниже
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.screen__inner {
    position: relative;
    &::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 115%;
      height: 150%;
      bottom: 0;
      background: url(../img/img.png) no-repeat;
      background-position:  100% 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="screen">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="screen__inner">
        <section>
          <h2>Вы можете научиться<br>зарабатывать также</h2>
          <h3>видео курс "Управление рисками"</h3>
          <h4>за $49 вы получите знания, которые будете<br>использовать всегда</h4>
          <button>Купить курс</button>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: overflow: hidden;

Comment: и чему мне это присвоить? пробовал два варианта:
html {
overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
overflow-x: hidden;
}